# How is snakemake script name accessed?

Tags: snakemake

Is there a way to access the name of the snakefile that is being run with snakemake?  It seems to be accessible by parsing sys.argv, but I'm wondering if there is a variable available that includes environmental information like that?

Answer (score 4):

Within a snakefile, you can access the full path of the snakefile being used via `workflow.snakefile`. The `workflow` object exposes other invocation information; you can explore the full range of attributes and methods via `print(dir(workflow))` (within a snakefile).

If you want just the filename of the `Snakefile`, you can parse it out with `os.path.basename()`:

```py
import os
print(os.path.basename(workflow.snakefile))
```